# What is the use of processRequest(request,response) in doPost()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

what is the purpose of calling `requestProcess(request,response)` method in `doPost()`. You can see the code in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv0bu.png).

Comment: Do you mean `processRequest`?

Comment: sorry yes processRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProcessRequest` is just another user defined method.

To make understanding easier (Perform same action for both get and post requests), the default code generated for [doPost](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) and [doGet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) end up calling the method `ProcessRequest` so they have the same behavior.
(*I mean both Get and Post requests end up doing the same operation.*)

Instead of processRequest, you could even write any method (say customRequestProcessor) and call it from `doPost` or `doGet` methods. It has **no special meaning** and it need not exist either.

> What is the use of processRequest(request,response) in doPost()

The action that needs to happen when user invokes this servlet should ideally go in this method (*provided this is invoked from your doPost method*).

Comment: so in which method i must get request from form if its method is doPost()?

Comment: When you submit request from a form, it will ideally call `doPost` method. and whatever is the body of the doPost that gets executed. In the example code you pasted, since the body of the doPost said invoke `processRequest`, it will call processRequest Function. So `processrequest` has no special meaning except that it is a user-defined function.